# RemoveRange doesnot show in intellisense

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework-6, intellisense

I'm working on ASP.NET Webforms with EF 6.

I've done other projects with Webforms and I've got IntelliSense with `RemoveRange`, but in this project particularly, it doesn't show up!

It only shows `Remove` when I type

```
someContext.someTable.
```

I even tried `using System.Data.Entity;` because that is where this is supposed to come from, but no luck.

Comment: is someTable DbSet or IDbSet?

Comment: Regardless it shows up or not, does it compile?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto It does not compile. It shows error

Comment: @Lowkey I'm pretty sure it's DbSet. Never seen IDbSet until now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved the problem by 
getting all the indexes.. (primary key)
and put them in a list, and then 
called remove to every each one of them using for (or foreach)
loop.

I'm not sure this is a good practice to do things right,
but it certainly works beautifully and it's simple,
and personally I don't see if it might cause any kind of trouble
(if you don't mess up with the indexes as I did at my first time)

Comment: so glad to hear that your issue is solved, please mark your reply as answer and that will help other community members to easier search this useful information, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design and please check this information: [Entity Framework Design Meeting Notes, on May 16, 2013](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Design%20Meeting%20Notes%20-%20May%2016%2C%202013) and the team recognized the potential for breaking changes.

If you still want to use it, you can have a look at [this similar issue](https://forums.asp.net/t/1978828.aspx?Why%20is%20there%20no%20AddRange%20method%20for%20System%20Data%20Entity%20IDbSet%20T%20) and solved it with extension methods as below:

```
public static class R2VDbContextExtensionMethods
{
    public static IEnumerable<TEntity> AddRange<TEntity>(this IDbSet<TEntity> dbset, IEnumerable<TEntity> entitiesToAdd) where TEntity : class
    {
        return ((DbSet<TEntity>)dbset).AddRange(entitiesToAdd);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TEntity> RemoveRange<TEntity>(this IDbSet<TEntity> dbset, IEnumerable<TEntity> entitiesToDelete) where TEntity : class
    {
        return ((DbSet<TEntity>)dbset).RemoveRange(entitiesToDelete);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have absolutely no idea how you know all this stuff, but thank you.

Comment: it gives a stackoverflow exception... however, nice to know why it is not working